# Given a diameter and species, how do I estimate a tree's size and age?

Tags: trees

I'm looking for a resource to help estimate the height and age of a tree from its diameter (75+ inch circumference). My property has mature Red Pines and I'd like to estimate their ages and heights. I understand there will be a "fudge factor" in any resource I find but it's a start. I found some research by USDA - Forestry but none of the species included in the research are even close to a Red Pine.

Update #1 - The trees are part of unmanaged forest property I own. Most of the trees are less than 30 years old due to a wildfire. The rest, however, survived the fire and are much older than the new growth ( 30+ inch diameter). The only watering these trees get is from the sky. The soil is sand with river rock encountered 5-10 feet beneath the surface.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely sure that's possible. There would be a large fudge factor, because I'd think a trees growth rate on a particular year would determine it's future circumference and that growth is based on variable factors, such as the amount of light, water, and nutrients they are provided. Also, their location is important.

For instance, the art of bonsai is about making young trees look ancient, but you can look on many bonsai sites and see wild trees that sprouted in a rock crevice on the top of a mountain and they are hundreds of years old, but maybe only a few inches in diameter, because everything they need to grow in extremely limited.

It's possible someone could approximate age and size based on average or ideal growing conditions, but again, it seems to me like it'd be a pretty rough guess, with cutting the tree opens as the only means to truly determine the age.

You could see if anyone in your area is clearing similar trees off the property, housing developers being excellent resources and count the ring on a tree of similar size.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Dalton's answer - growth is variable depending on conditions and environment, but there is a table of approximate ages in relation to girth of the trunk. See link here, it might be useful, but it is dependent on identifying the species of tree, since they're all genetically programmed with different growth rates. These tables tend to be more accurate for trees growing in forest, or natural, conditions - for street/garden trees, it's not so easy, because they may have been cared for, not left to their own devices (extra water when its dry, fertilized, etc).

http://forestry.about.com/od/silviculture/a/Estimating-A-Trees-Age.htm

This link does mention Red Pine:

http://mdc.mo.gov/your-property/your-trees-and-woods/backyard-tree-care/how-old-tree